# Inbox notifications seem to have stopped

Tags: bug

Today I received replies to two comments I'd made on different questions, but I didn't get a red "1" next to my inbox as usually happens. The notifications are there in my inbox, if I go to it by clicking on "StackExchange" and then "inbox", but they appear as if they've already been read. Has something about this feature been changed recently, or is the problem on my end?

Comment: Does this ping you? I get this problem as well, though it happens rarely.

Comment: @Manishearth no, no ping...

Comment: (Maybe I should just re-start my browser and see if that helps. But I *really* don't want to do that, I have nearly 100 tabs open that I don't want to reload.)

Comment: Could be your apps doing something. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/apps/5477, the first app may be buggy and misbehaving. Or...logging out and logging back in to Physics.SE should do the trick.

Comment: @Manishearth ok, I have removed the first app (I never use it anyway) and logged out and in again - will see if that makes a difference...

Comment: ...one or other of those actions appears to have fixed it, at least for now.

Comment: @Manishearth: Like you've said, it appears *rarely*. If your comment already exists in the post and the author responds your without a ping, we'll get notified anyway. But, I haven't experienced any bug related to the inbox except during the cleanup when it is read-only (and I get logged out) :P